# iphone 5c bluetooth pairing with Mac: "the device does not have the necessary services"

Tags: iphone, macos, bluetooth

As seen in the screenshot the iphone 5c is discovered via bluetooth; but the pairing is not successful due to missing `services`.

[image]

The Iphone says

```
  My Devices
       mellyrn     Not Connected
```

where `mellyrn` is the hostname of the mac.   So what `services` are referred to here?

I am on `El Capitan`.

Answer (score 1):

from what I've gathered, the "services" can be related to filesharing or simply because either one of the devices refuses to understand the other...

based on the following

> iOs devices will not pair to computers except for Personal Hotspot. For AirDrop, you need to have bluetooth and Wifi on, and simply turn on Airdrop on each device. Pairing is not necessary.

source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6795203?start=0&tstart=0

it seems to use airdrop, the personal hotspot needs to be disabled

and also

> - Instead of connect to the devices using the "Browse device" where I have the same error than you, I went to "Set Up Bluetooth Device" and it works
> - went to preference- sharing- turned bluetooth sharing on
> - bottom of options where you'll see "Send File To Bluetooth Device". The device may show as "Disconnected" but click on it anyway

from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4207524?start=15&tstart=0

see also  `macworld co uk /how-to/mac-software/how-use-airdrop-on-macs-wirelessly-share-files-update-3500407/`
which basically says airdrop can be buggy - turn on wifi and bluetooth, open airdrop on mac and "be patient"

in my case I got the same error message, but pairing/connecting wasn't working as I was using an iPhone 4s (and it needs 5 or later).

Comment: thx - I am not using AirDrop but just trying to use the Personal Hotspot

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and was getting a same error. 
Problem was my AirDrop setting in iPhone was "Discoverable by Contacts only" I changed to "Everyone" and it worked :)